# Testing for sameness between arrays of different sizes: "DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future"

Tags: python, numpy

I am dealing with images. In the pipeline, either the *original* image or the *edited* image might be returned. To complicate things further, the returned image can have the same shape, so testing for equal shapes is not the way to go. I want to follow different steps depending on if the original/edited image is returned. If I use the `==` sign, it returns a warning every time:

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future

**Reproduce the warning using this code:**

```
import numpy as np

picture_1 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100, 3))
picture_2 = picture_1[10:-10, 10:-10]

print(picture_1 == picture_2)
```

So, how do I test for equality with arrays of a different size?

*Note that existing answers to this question have only focused on avoiding the comparison. In my case, the comparison is purposeful.*

Comment: What does equality of two different size numpy arrays represent?

Comment: if the returned image corresponds to the original image

Comment: You want to check if `picture_2` is same as `picture_1`?

Comment: Numpy `A==B` compares the arrays element -wise.  That's only meaningful if they have the same shape.  If it works, you'll an array the same size, but with boolean values.  You need to be clear - to yourself, and use - about what you mean by `equal`.  A fuzzy notion of equality does not work.

Comment: In your example `picture_2` is a view of `picture_1`.  Is that the same or not?  Shape is clearly different, but it pixel values haven't changed.  What if it was a slice plus a `copy`?  Same values, but not a shared data buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first testing for equality of shape, then for equality of items if the shapes are equal. Ultimately, if the shapes are not equal, the second comparison is never useful.

```
import numpy as np

picture_1 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100, 3))
picture_2 = picture_1[10:-10, 10:-10]

print(np.shape(picture_1)==np.shape(picture_2))
if np.shape(picture_1)==np.shape(picture_2):
    print(picture_1 == picture_2)
```

If I'm misunderstanding and still trying to avoid the comparison, please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's `==` is for comparing the values, so it is not the way to go.
If I understood correctly, I think what you are looking for is `numpy.ndarray.base`.

```
import numpy as np

picture_1 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100, 3))
picture_2 = picture_1[10:-10, 10:-10]

print(picture_2.base is picture_1) # True
```

As said in the [official doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html), this code checks if `picture_2` based on `picture_1`. In other 'numpy' words, it checks if `picture_2` is a `view` of `picture_1`.

---

Or mabye you want to use `base` as something like this?
This checks if the base `picture_1` which `picture_2` was cropped from is (value wise) same as `picture_0`.

```
import numpy as np

picture_0 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100, 3))
picture_1 = np.copy(picture_0)
picture_2 = picture_1[10:-10, 10:-10]
picture_1_mod = np.copy(picture_0)+1 # mod means modified.
picture_2_mod = picture_1_mod[10:-10, 10:-10]

print(picture_2.base == picture_0) # Array of Trues
print(picture_2_mod.base == picture_0) # Array of Falses
```